# disable editable text - it should not be editable

Tags: angularjs

I would have a question concerning editable-text.
If I click the text, an input opens and I can edit the text. Is it possible to disable this behavior in that way, that the input doesn't open?
I have tried it with **ng-disable** and **ng-readonly** - but with no success.

```
<span editable-text="myText">{{ myText }}</span>
```

Thanks a lot for help!

**[EDIT]**
I have tried a lot with this example:

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/26/)

but with no success. It would be great if someone could help me. Thanks a lot!

**[EDIT]**
Is there any working solution? I have tried a lot but with no success. 
I would be very thankful if someone could give my a hint how to solve this issue.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just remove the `editable-text` property?

```
<span>{{ myText }}</span>
```

Comment: This would be a possibility in generel (I don't know how I do this with AngularJS, and jquery is dirty) but with AngularJS the DOM shouldn't be manipulated - therefore I hope there is a directive.

Comment: Would there any possibility how to remove and add attributes in AngularJS? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no option to disable the editable field. Therefore can do a workaround to get over with this problem.

```
<span ng-if="showEditable" editable-text="myText">{{ myText }}</span>
<span ng-if="!showEditable">{{ myText }}</span>
```

You can include this functionality in a directive too.

Comment: I had this idea too. The problem is, that the view is very time critical and I view about 400 elements (divs and spans). If I double the elements, I have 800 spans - and this decreases performance. I had another idea: To cover my table this an additional layer would solve my problem. If this layer is clicked than nothing happens. If this layer is removed than everything works like before.

Answer (score 0):

Use `edit-disabled` attribute. For example-

```
<span editable-text="myText" edit-disabled="!showEditable">{{ myText }}</span>
```

Reference: https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#edit-disabled